# PHP LINUX WINDOWS ldap_bind success on WinXP but not Linux

Tags: php, windows, linux, ldap

I have a PHP script running on Apache on Windows XP that can successfully do LDAP authentication.  I copied this same script to an Apache on Linux Red Hat and ldap_bind call nows gives me the following error:

Warning: ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

I can ping the LDAP server from both Linux and Windows machines.

I compared PHP, Apache, and LDAP versions and found the following:

Linux Red Hat machine:
PHP version: 5.1.6
Apache version: 2.2.3
LDAP: OpenLDAP, RCS Version: $ld: ldap.c, v 1.161.2.3 2006/01/01 12:50:08, API version 3001, Vendor Version 20343

my local Windows machine:
PHP version: 5.3.8
Apache version: 2.2.21
LDAP: OpenLDAP, RCS Version: $ld: ldap.c 313665 2011/07/25 11:42:53, API version 3001, Vendor Version 20319

are there any known issues with ldap_bind on earlier Linux or Apache versions?  Does anyone have any ideas why the same PHP script does LDAP authentication succcessfully from a Windows machine but not a Linux machine?

Comment: Here is my PHP code : $ldaphost="ldap://some.server.com:3268"; if (!($connect = ldap_connect($ldaphost))) {  
 die ("Could not connect to LDAP server"); 
} if ($connect) {
 $result = ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
} $ldapbind = ldap_bind($connect, $username, $password);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now on the Linux machine.

Both the Windows and Linux machine were using OpenLDAP, but the LDAP on the Linux machine was not properly configured to connect to the LDAP server.  The fix was to alter a file /etc/ldap.conf.  The settings in this file were not correctly set.  Trial and error altering the settings in this file to match what was used in Windows.  The key setting seemed to be port.  port in this file was originally set to 389, supposedly the default.  Changed this to 3268. Restarted Apache and tried the authentication again and it worked.  Also commented out 'base' parameter.  Base not needed since LDAP is in a Windows domain.